# Asking questions with UML diagrams instead of code

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Can I ask a question with a UML class diagram instead of code? What about instead of *some* code? The kind of questions I'm interested in asking are about software architecture, not low-level coding issues.

Comment: @nhgrif Not really the best duplicate-candidate IMO. I'm quite sure this question has been asked before on our meta, but that question you are linking to is not *asking* about that part.

Comment: But the answers address this exactly, don't they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the entire question consists of UML diagrams and no code, then it's off-topic for this site.  Overall, the specific code to be reviewed *must* be embedded in the post itself.  It's okay to include UML diagrams as supplemental material, but we cannot review *that* specifically.  If your question is primarily about UML diagrams (software architecture as you say), then it won't fit on this site.

Here's the relevant off-topic section found in the [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and
>   instead is a generally applicable question about…
>
> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice
>     regarding X?")
> - Tools, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - How to add a feature to or solve a problem with your code
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - **Higher-level architecture and design of software systems**
>
> then your question is **off-topic** for this site.